# Swift is connected to the SQLite DB, but I can not find the file

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am new in Swift, and today I followed the tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/385-sqlite-with-swift-tutorial-getting-started) (getting started with SQLite). 
Therefore, my code is basically the same:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import SQLite.Swift
import PlaygroundSupport

enum SQLiteError: Error {
    case OpenDatabase(message: String)
    case Prepare(message: String)
    case Step(message: String)
    case Bind(message: String)
}

class SQLiteDatabase {
    fileprivate let dbPointer: OpaquePointer?

    fileprivate init(dbPointer: OpaquePointer?) {
        self.dbPointer = dbPointer
    }

    deinit {
        sqlite3_close(dbPointer)
    }

    static func open(path: String) throws -> SQLiteDatabase {
        var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
        // 1
        if sqlite3_open(path, &db) == SQLITE_OK {
            // 2
            return SQLiteDatabase(dbPointer: db)
        } else {
            // 3
            defer {
                if db != nil {
                    sqlite3_close(db)
                }
            }

            if let errorPointer = sqlite3_errmsg(db) {
                let message = String.init(cString: errorPointer)
                throw SQLiteError.OpenDatabase(message: message)
            } else {
                throw SQLiteError.OpenDatabase(message: "No error message provided from sqlite.")
            }
        }
    }
}

let db: SQLiteDatabase

do {
    db = try SQLiteDatabase.open(path: "")
    print("Successfully opened connection to database.")
} catch SQLiteError.OpenDatabase(_) {
    print("Unable to open database. Verify that you created the directory described in the Getting Started section.")
    PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
}
```

The problem is that Swift confirms me that he has "Successfully opened connection to database." But the point is that I never created a file for the database... and I don't know where I can locate the actual file.

The path of the database should be the racine because the variable is set to the default folder ("")

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the default folder is one created by Xcode, something like `/Users/"your username"/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<Project name>...`

To check you could add the following where you open the database

```
let current = FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath
print(current)
```

If you look at the tutorial you notice they did use a specific folder.

Comment: Ok thanks! Do you know how can I refer the folder of the project himself? Because when I'll publish the app, I can't let the path to "/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/"...

Comment: No I don't know that exactly but the folder I referred to is just a temporary one and have nothing to do with the published app. I suppose you either store it in the main bundle or outside the app in some pre-defined folder that you have decided